# Why would I need forward class declaration in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, class

In this code:

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>

class QPushButton;
class Window : public QWidget
{
public:
    explicit Window(QWidget *parent = 0);
private:
    QPushButton *m_button;
};

#endif // WINDOW_H
```

why would I need to forward the class QPushButton declaration? what will happen if I don't do that? because I have removed that and the program has been compiled

this is the .cpp file of this header:

```
#include "window.h"

#include <QPushButton>

Window::Window(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    // Set size of the window
    setFixedSize(100, 50);

    // Create and position the button
    m_button = new QPushButton("Hello World", this);
    m_button->setGeometry(10, 10, 80, 30);
}
```

Comment: Because it has to be declared before it can be used otherwise the compiler has no idea what it is.

Comment: Don't count on headers to include other headers for you.

Comment: @chris You never know. What about `iosfwd`

Comment: @Rapptz, Well, some are specifically designed to do that, but not in general. For example, relying on `<string>` to be included when `<iostream>` is will break eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a pointer to a `QPushButton` in the declaration of the class `Window`. That's why you have to `#include <QPushButton>` before using it, or at least to tell the compiler that it exists and it's declared further in your code with a forward declaration.
If nothing happens when you remove the forward declaration from your header file is because somewhere before it is included or declared. May be qwidget.h ore one of its included headers is doing that for you... or a .h file generated by the "Qt User Interface Compiler" in the case you were using Qt designer forms.

But as @chris said: "Don't count on headers to include other headers for you."

There's no extra job in doing it explicitly.